# Grouped windows show script name instead of title in window list

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gnome

I have a Python application using PyGTK.  If the title of the main window is "Foo", "Foo" will be displayed in GNOME's window list.  As the window list is currently configured, it will always group windows from the same application.  When I open a modal window on top of the main, the title in the window list changes to "foo.py" or whatever the Python script is named.  When windows aren't grouped, the two windows appear as "Foo" and "Bar" in the list.

How can I control what is displayed in the window list when the windows are grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped windows use the application name as label, which AFAIK defaults to argv[0]. This should be modifiable using [`g_set_application_name`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-set-application-name) (`glib.set_application_name` in PyGTK). If that doesn't work, try `g_set_prgname`.

**Update:** Old versions of PyGTK has them in the `gobject` module, so try that. Don't forget to check both functions, as set_application_name is rather new.

If that still doesn't work, the last resort is to use ctypes, e.g.

```
import ctypes
libglib = ctypes.CDLL('libglib-2.0.so')
libglib.g_set_application_name("Hello World")
```

And if that doesn't work, your glib is probably just too old; I'm not aware of any more workarounds.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.4.3 with PyGTK 2.10.1.  Was this function added in a more recent version?  `glib` seems to be missing from my installation.

Comment: This answer is correct but unfortunately my version of PyGTK isn't new enough to use it.  Also, [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes) wasn't available until Python 2.5.

Comment: Hm, maybe try [dl](http://docs.python.org/library/dl). I can't test because it's gone from Python 2.7, but it should be something like `import dl; dl.open('libglib-2.0.so').call('g_set_application_name', "Hello")`

Comment: No luck there, I get `SystemError: module dl requires sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) == sizeof(char*)`.  Thanks, though.